# How to run GitHub Actions workflow only if the pushed files are in a specific folder

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a folder structure that looks something like this.

```
- folder1
  - file1
  - *other files*
- folder2
  - file1
  - *other files*
- .gitignore
- package.json
- *other files*
```

I want to run my GitHub Actions workflow on push, only if any of the changed/pushed files are located in the `folder1` directory/folder.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths -> you can reference this link for different variety of option for triggering a GitHub actions pipeline. And as VonC has mentioned the correct answer, i don't want to repeat the same.

Comment: As an addition, see the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-file-paths) for all possible filter patterns.

Comment: It's crazy GitHub isn't better at explaining how to do such a simple thing.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The normal syntax involves [a path filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore)

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - folder1/**
```

If that is not enough, you also have the [GitHub Action Path Filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter).

Comment: It is working for pushed files only but not working for pushed with previous commits in the same branch.
Does anybody know how to run an action for all the files in the PR not only recently pushed? If I am running tests I want to run them for previous changes as well.

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky Can you illustrate your use case in a separate question?

Comment: Appreciate your help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772740/run-github-actions-if-branch-has-files-from-a-specific-directory

Answer (score 28):

Path filters only work at workflow level.

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'sub-project/**'
```

If you want to apply this at job level, look for [`changed-files`](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer bc it actually answers OPs question.

Answer (score 23):

You can also add branches and remove some lines using square brackets.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
    paths: ['folder/**']
```

Comment: is this going to push to such a branch when the path ALSO matches? basically, I'd like to know if there is an OR or AND between the conditions!

Comment: AND condition. So it will trigger only if it matches the branch name and path.

Answer (score 20):

You will need this if also wanting to filter pull request runs

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'folder1/**'
  pull_request:
    paths: 
    - 'folder1/**'
```

Answer (score 12):

The above answers are correct, but they will not execute workflows again if the workflows themselves has changed. If this is something you want, make sure to include your workflows directory in the paths filters:

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'my-nodejs-application-directory/**'
      - '.github/workflows/**'
```