# How to run git actions conditionally based on folder match

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this git action setup where I want to run `regression` only on `folder1` and not `folder2`.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        dir: ['./folder1', 'folder2']

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: Run regression tests
      run: npm run regression
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run github action only if the pushed files are in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822219/how-to-run-github-action-only-if-the-pushed-files-are-in-a-specific-folder)

Comment: It's also in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Comment: @fredrik The answer in link mentions about `on push`  but not about conditions on git steps

Comment: Define different jobs for it? Having a "build" job that also runs test does not make sense to me.

Comment: @fredrik Why not? We are running tests on push..

Comment: I'd do one "tests" job/build and one for tests.

Comment: It does not seem possible to condition a step inside a job, only jobs and actions. You could do it as a shell script check - but it would not prevent it from running - just pass on the npm command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if` conditions to do this.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
        dir: ['./folder1', 'folder2']
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm ci
      run: npm run lint
    - name: Run unit
      run: npm run test:unit
      working-directory: ${{ matrix.dir }}
    - name: Run integration
      if: ${{ matrix.dir == './folder1' }}
      run: npm run test:integration
      working-directory: ${{ matrix.dir }}
```

Comment: Actually `dir: ['./folder1', 'folder2']` doesn't work

Comment: Because you are not referencing it anywhere. You should have something called `working-directory` and call `matrix.dir`.

Comment: Oh okay. I was not able to find an example on this. Could you please add it to your answer

Comment: I've edited my answer along with `working-directory`