How to run GitHub actions if path changed OR push to main?
I have a repository like this:
backend/...
frontend/...
README.md

I configured workflows to only run when changes were made to a specific path. For example, the backend workflow only runs for changes made to backend files:
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - backend/**

Now for commits to main main I would like the workflow to run on any file change. How can this be implemented? I see that there is a paths constraint (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73343353/3423035), but as far as I can tell, this is an AND condition (i.e., if files xxx changed AND branch is yyy).

You can't, at least not from on. As you say, on.push.paths with on.push.branches is an and, not or. So you'd have to allow more workflows to start, and conditionally end some of them straight away (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090138/3001761 on the question you already linked).
